# Renci SSH NET Upload Large File Failure

Tags: ssh.net

I've been using a .NET DLL by Renci SSH NET which transfers the files from local machine to secure FTP. It was working fine for small files but this has a problem while uploading large files through my application. I increased the buffer time, operation time out but it still doesn't upload. When I debugged my code, it stuck at the point where I'm uploading & it does not even throw any error.

Any Suggestions Please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per your description, it's not clear if the issue caused by your codes or by the SFTP server, so I would like to suggest:

1. Use a ftp client to upload the same file to the SFTP server to see if that OK.
2. If OK, then you can use network monitor tool, such as **wireshark**, **tcpdump**, to check if the issue is caused by network unstable.
3. Also, by using the network monitor tool, you can check if the upload process stop at the same point every time.

Hopefully that would helpful.

Comment: My code is running fine because when I tested for small files less than 1 MB they are getting uploaded on to SFTP. I'm thinking that the problem was with the DLL. Did you try and use this Renci SSH component with large file atleast 20MB.

Comment: Yes,  I tested the SFTP upload by using SSH.NET version 2016.0.0 on Win10 (VS 2015), the sshd on CentOS 7.3. The codes came from  [https://gist.github.com/piccaso/d963331dcbf20611b094](https://gist.github.com/piccaso/d963331dcbf20611b094). An 65 MB file could be uploaded successfully. So I believe the DLL should be OK.

Comment: Yes Caleb, the DLL with Version 2016.0.0 is working from windows 7. But I'll have to check it in Server 2003 if it is compatible or not. Also, is it possible to increase the upload speed. I tried uploading 100 MB file with buffer size 16 KB, time span 1800sec & it is taking around 35 min to upload.